# Sharing or accessing large immutable data across Akka actors

Tags: akka

I'm working on an application that does a lot of number crunching on a single immutable data structure. (A collection of very large arrays--essentially a big matrix. Let's say a typical size would be 200 columns by 100,000 rows of doubles.) A lot of the computation can be parallelized in different ways, and I would like to leverage the Akka actor model to tackle the problem.

I'm worried about having to pass this matrix (or parts of it) around in messages because I think that would involve a whole lot of copying and serialization.

Am I over-thinking this problem? (That is, if a supervisor actor passes some of arrays of this matrix to its subordinates, is the Akka runtime smart enough to just pass this as a reference--assuming they are kept on the same JVM--as opposed to serializing everything into a message for passing?)

I guess a simpler way of asking the question is: should one avoid a situation where massive data structures are passed in messages?

Just to reiterate: this data in question is completely and totally immutable. It will never change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Akka will only serialize messages if you send to a [remote actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/remoting.html) (or, by extension, to a cluster node). Remote doesn't necessarily mean, that proper networking is involved; it can just be a different JVM on the same machine (over the loopback interface). If you have one actor system on one JVM without any remoting, then only a reference is passed, in the same manner as if you were to put the message on a Queue and have a different Thread read it.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, very large data structures should not be passed to remote actors.  Instead, upload your data structure to some sort of persistent blob store (HDFS, S3, etc) and send a message telling the remote actor that new data is available for processing.

Comment: Thanks. I figured in extreme cases that would be the case. But the relative question is what "very large" means. In my application, I was thinking of a collection of about 10 arrays of doubles (or sometimes integers) that might each have a size ranging from 10 thousand to 10 million. On the smaller end, that looks like just a few megabytes, so I'm guessing that's okay, but I don't know what the upper threshold should be. The important thing is that speed is a critical architectural factor.